# Can't create select element with returned json data from Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm making an ajax call to retrieve some JSON objects. I get them right. but the problem is when I want to create a select element from returned JSON, it doesn't create one or seemed to be.

My JavaScript so far:

```
jQuery("#make").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    jQuery.getJSON("<?php echo site_url('ajax/get/models'); ?>", {
        makeId: value
    },

    function (data) {
        if (data != "false") {
            var modelsSelect = jQuery.createElement('select');
            var modelsOptions = "";
            var id;
            var model
            jQuery.each(data, function () {
                jQuery.each(this, function (key, value) {
                    if (key == "id") {
                        id = value;
                    } else {
                        model = value;
                    }
                });
                modelsOptions += "<option value=" + id + ">" + model + "</option>"
            });
            modelsSelect.innerHTML = modelsOptions;
            jQuery("#model").html = modelsSelect;
        } else {
            alert("false");
        }
    });
});
```

my returned JSON Format:

```
Object { id="28", model="test model"}
```

There could be **n** number of JSON objects in returned response from ajax call.

Comment: One small side note... trying to set the `.innerHTML` of a `<select>` element in older Internet Explorer browsers will fail. IE8 and below for sure will fail - I can't remember if this was fixed in IE9 or IE10.

Comment: @scunliffe, so what should i use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `createElement` method in jQuery

`jQuery.createElement` should be `document.createElement`

---

Also no need to loop over the objects' properties, you can access them by the key directly

```
jQuery.each(data, function (index, item) {
    modelsOptions += "<option value=" + item.id + ">" + item.model + "</option>"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
jQuery("#model").html = modelsSelect;
```

to

```
jQuery("#model").html(modelsSelect);
```

---

Reference

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: still doesn't replace the empty <select id="model"> with the generated one. is my code right?when ajax result is returned there could be n objects with the format above.